# preserve client side HTML markup and retain after postback

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am building a user search filter where we can specify a number of criteria's, one per each row of a HTML table.

I am building a dynamic table using jquery on the client side, the table starts off with one row(default) on page load with a "+" image on the last `<td>` which when clicked I am appending a new row to the table, and this can repeat for any number of rows as shown below. Once the search button is clicked, I am bringing back results based on criteria selected. But I also need to preserve the current criteria table after postback(due to search button).

[image: The Dynamic Table image]

Any ideas on how to do this? I have tried putting all of the HTML for the table in a hiddenfield but I get a RequestValidationError for obvious security reasons. I have the individual selected values in each row saved in hidden variables which I am using in code behind to build the search and bring the results, do I need to rebuild the table on the client side using the values I have? Is that the only option? I also tried converting the HTML for the table into text and putting it in hidden variable, but I am not able to convert it back into HTML after the postback, it is rendering as text inside the table, below is the code for it, any help/input is appreciated.

HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" runat="server" value="0" id="hdnCriteriaTable" />
```

jQuery:

on button click, before postback(client side):

```
jQuery("[id*=hdnCriteriaTable]").val(jQuery("#dynamicCriteriaTable tbody").html().replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;"));
```

on page load after postback(client side):

```
    if (jQuery("[id*=hdnispostback]").val() == "1")
    {
//commented out lines below are different ways I tried to make it work.
//the one with hardcoded td's is the one that renders perfectly as HTML inside the table
        jQuery("#dynamicCriteriaTable>tbody").empty();
        var criteriaTableHTML = jQuery("[id*=hdnCriteriaTable]").val().replace("&amp;lt;", /</g).replace("&amp;gt;", />/g).replace("&quot;", "\"");
        jQuery.parseHTML(criteriaTableHTML);
        //jQuery("#dynamicCriteriaTable>tbody").append(jQuery("[id*=hdnCriteriaTable]").val().replace("&amp;lt;", /</g).replace("&amp;gt;", />/g).replace("&quot;", "\"").toHtml());
        //jQuery("#dynamicCriteriaTable>tbody").append("<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>")
        jQuery("#dynamicCriteriaTable>tbody").append(criteriaTableHTML);
        //alert(jQuery("#dynamicCriteriaTable").html());
        //jQuery("#dynamicCriteriaTable").toHtml();
    }
```

This is how HTML is being rendered inside the table:

[image: Rendered HTML image]

Comment: Does `jQuery.parseHTML(x)` actually modify `x`, or just return a parsed version of `x`? Have you tried `criteriaTableHTML = jQuery.parseHTML(criteriaTableHTML);`?

Comment: `jQuery.parseHTML(x)` modifies `x`. Either way I just tried setting it back to the same variable and I still get the same result.

Comment: Try one thing for me. You can decode an HTML string by creating a pseudo textbox, populating it, and then re-fetching it's value, like I've done in [**this JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/tr_santi/hqgf5zy5/1/). Perhaps you can try to actually decode your HTML by using this method, prior to appending it to your tbody.

Comment: @Santi: what an idea, it worked. It is not retaining the selected values of the controls though. I will see if rebuilding the table is a better solution in terms of time and cleanliness as `cuniculus` suggested. If I can get the values to work with your solution pretty quickly I would go with that.

Comment: wondering why the HTML does not have the value set as "Mary" and "Bob" in value for the input field, they are not getting populated. I would think it should have the values set as well.

Comment: While it may seem like a pain initially, working with the data as opposed to HTML will grant you much more flexibility.

Answer (score 2):

If I were you, I would rebuild the table from the values; it's clean, and you can always write a function that automates the build.

However, if you want to pass it *in toto* as HTML, you'll need to escape your tags somehow. I would start by replacing `<` and `>` with `&lt;` and `&gt;`, respectively, and if that still give you a requestValidationError, use another pair of delimiters.